# Command Line OSX: Configuring the PATH variable

Tags: bash, shell

I've tried to set up a folder called `bin` in my user directory.  Sadly, my first attempt of appending the new directory was incorrect as I missed a `"`.  I tried opening up the `.bash_profile` to try and delete my first attempt, but due to not really knowing what I was doing when saving I get these errors when I open the `bash`.

```
Last login: Mon Dec 23 11:13:39 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/daz/.bash_profile: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/daz/.bash_profile: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
darryls-mini:~ daz$ cat ~/.bash_profile
PATH=$PATH:~/bin"
PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
darryls-mini:~ daz$
```

The first line after `cat` is the incorrect one.  This is the result of me trying to delete the `bash_profile` file and re-saving it using `pico ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just edit the file and delete the line? Alternatively, this command will do it for you (assuming that your `~/.bash_profile` is otherwise empty, as it seems to be in your post):

```
echo 'PATH="$PATH:~/bin"' > ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin"
```

which is causing the unexpected EOF while looking for matching `` `"' ``.

Observe the quoting.  You probably wanted to say:

```
PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what the problem is:

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

You close the quotes without opening them:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin"
```

Change it to

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

or

```
PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```